# Javascript: Software for rename functions and variables

Tags: javascript, encryption, rename

anybody knows a program or script or tool that **renames functions and variables** for a list of Javascript files?

A program like http://javascript-source.com/index.html just open source or freeware?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you even try to google for that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript

Comment: I googled for it and found just that one tool. I don't wanna minify the code by removing comments and line spaces etc. I want to rename functions and vars to function a,b,c,d,e etc. through all selected javascript files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) will obfuscate your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually i'm searching only for the function to rename all functions and vars over a set of files.